# Javascript functions in a single file causing conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have all my JavaScript functions in a single file called site.js

This file is declared at the bottom in my master layout page for faster loading.

However I've noticed that some of my functions don't work unless I switch their order in the file. E.g the following order of the two functions prevent the datetimepicker widget from working.

```
$(function() {
  $(".js-multi-select").select2();
});

$(function () {
  $('#start_dt').datetimepicker({
     showTodayButton: true,
     format: 'D MMM YYYY HH:mm',
     defaultDate: moment().hours(0).minute(0)
   });
});
```

If I switch the order and place the datetimepicker function before the select2 fucntion then it seems to work.

```
$(function () {
  $('#start_dt').datetimepicker({
     showTodayButton: true,
     format: 'D MMM YYYY HH:mm',
     defaultDate: moment().hours(0).minute(0)
   });
});

$(function() {
  $(".js-multi-select").select2();
});
```

Note the page on which I have my datetimepicker field doesnt have a select2 dropdown list field and the page on which I have a select2 dropdown list doesnt always have a datetimepicker field. I don't want to have a dozen javascript files for each function which is why I've put them all in one file.

Why is the above functions behaving this way and what is the fix so that they work regardless of whatever order they are declared in.

Comment: Getting any errors in the console?

Comment: It's likely we'd need more information, like anything from the JS console on  a page that doesn't work, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing select2 is erroring out. What's in the js console?

Comment: Why are you defining `$(function(){})` twice? Try to add `$(".js-multi-select").select2();` after the `datetimepicker` function

Comment: @DavidLaberge That's potentially a good idea (unless the files are being concatenated during a JS build step) but shouldn't cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your second doc.ready function and put the code inside your first.

```
$(function () {
   $('#start_dt').datetimepicker({
     showTodayButton: true,
     format: 'D MMM YYYY HH:mm',
     defaultDate: moment().hours(0).minute(0)
  });
  $(".js-multi-select").select2();
});
```

Comment: That's unrelated; there can be multiple `$(function() { ...})` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>select2</title>
<script src="./jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link href="./jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="./jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#start_dt').datetimepicker(); 
 });

$(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="start_dt"/>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a chance that something else is going on for you.

Because in the above page I tried renaming class js-example-basic-single to js-example-basic-single1 so that select2's selector comes empty. select2() call does not produce an js error.

Two, I re-arranged the order of the calls but things work as expected.

Therefore, it should be something else IMHO.

Comment: The datetimepicker I'm using is the bootstrap datetimepicker and issue is with datetimepicker field not select2.  https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/